# Proof that n + (logn)^2 is O(n)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

The question is:

Show that `n + (logn)^2` is `O(n)`, so `n + (logn)^2 <= c * n`.

I can't find `n1` and `c` such that it is true for all `n > n1`.

Comment: your definition is incomplete n+(logn)^2 <= c*n for every n , n>=n1 where n1 is some constant. I assume n0 in your question is the constant n1 that i mentioned

Comment: You just need to proof that log n \in O(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**n** < **(*log* n)<sup>2</sup>** for values of **n** < 0.49

**Graph**:

[image]

blue line => **n** and the green line => **(*log* n)<sup>2</sup>**)

But for large **n**, **(*log* n)<sup>2</sup>** is negligible:

[image]

ThereFore, answer is **O(n)**

Answer (score 2):

We can prove that `logn^2 < n` for large enough `n`.

You can do this by doing limit of `n` goes to infinity for `logn^2 / n`. You can solve this limit by derivating numerator and denominator. You get `1/n`. We know that limit of `1/n`, `n` goes to `infinity`, is `0`.

Above implies that `logn^2 < n`, for large enough `n`, otherwise limit could never be `0`.

As `logn^2 < n` for large enough `n` this implies `log2^n = O(n)`.

Comment: For formal prove there exists some mathematical lemma, which states that existence/value of limit equals to: for each epsilon there exists n0 so that for each n > n0, |f(n) - lim(f(n))| < epsilon.

Comment: By induction on n it is not that hard to prove that lg(n)^2 < n, where lg() is the base 2 logarithm. Since any other logarithm is a constant multiple of lg(), the desired result follows from this fact.